# Creating binary matrix of each unique value from list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This question is conceptually similar to the question here: [Python Pandas: How to create a binary matrix from column of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487842/python-pandas-how-to-create-a-binary-matrix-from-column-of-lists?rq=1), but due to the size of my data, I do not want to convert into a pandas data frame.

I have a list of lists like the following,

```
list_ = [[5, 3, 5, 2], [6, 3, 2, 1, 3], [5, 3, 2, 5, 2]]
```

And I would like a binary matrix with each unique value as a column, and each sublist as a row.

How could this be done efficiently on over 100000 sublists with around 1000 items each?

Edit:

Example output is similar to the output in the question linked above, where the list could essentially be considered as:

```
list_ = [["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"]]

   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: You have a ragged list here. Can you explain what your output should look like?

Comment: How many unique values are there in total?  In the worst case, there will be `10**8` unique values, leading to `10**13` entries in the matrix, so you better have a few terabytes of memory to fit the matrix in.  More to the point, why are you transforming your data to a less memory-efficient representation in the first place?  Please provide more context about the problem you are solving.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I want to do a Fisher's exact test on each feature (number) and use it as a feature selection method. I have another list with a categorical assignment for each sublist. Perhaps it would be better to iterate through. If you could provide some insight on this that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x, lowercase=False)
m = cv.fit_transform(list_)

# To transform to dense matrix
m.todense()

# To get the values correspond to each column
cv.get_feature_names()

# If you need dummy columns, not count
m = (m > 0)
```

You may want to keep it as sparsed matrix for memory reason.

Answer (score 0):

The values in subsets(rows) will be a position of 1(True) and 0(False) in the rest of columns:

```
import numpy as np

list_ = [[5, 3, 5, 2], [6, 3, 2, 1, 3], [5, 3, 2, 5, 2]]

##################################
# convert to binary matrix
##################################
#find number of columns(dimenseion of matrix) 
nbr_of_columns = max(map(max, list_))+1 #maximun value in lists_

Mat = np.zeros((len(list_), nbr_of_columns), dtype=bool)
for i in range(0, len(list_)):
    for j in range(0, len(list_[i])):
        Mat[i, list_[i][j]] = True
        
print(Mat)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yisZC.png)