# Creating large sparse matrix from existing data

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix, array-broadcasting

Main part of my issue was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505207/creating-boolean-matrix-from-one-column-with-pandas).

However, my problem lies in fact that I have a large amount of data - two vectors of 265k (265 000) entries. I tried converting these arrays into sparse scipy matrices but the subtraction doesn't work that way because scipy cannot use numpy's broadcasting.

```
array_one = sparse.csr_matrix(df.id.values)
array_two = sparse.csr_matrix(df.id.values[:, None])
array_one - array_two throws MemoryError
```

Currently, I am looping over a 265k<sup>2</sup> entries and while it's working it's magic I'd like to ask for a more efficient solution to this for the future.

I'm doing this:

```
for j in range(265180):
    for i in range(265180):
        if arr1.data[j] == arr2.data[i]:
            rows.append(j)
            cols.append(i)
            data_items.append(1)
mat = sparse.coo_matrix(rows, cols, data_items)
```

Is there any way to convert Nx1 - 1xN numpy calculated matrix into NxN sparse matrix when N is large enough so that calculated matrix doesn't fit into the memory?

Comment: Is the number of distinct values in the input vectors limited in any way?  (For example, if the data type of the input vectors is 8 bit, then there are at most 256 distinct values in each array.)

Comment: They are floats. But I suppose I could round them up to 2 decimals or something similar. That would be 101 distinct values. Are you implying to convert the type to byte?

Comment: No, I was just thinking about methods that might take advantage of a small number of distinct values.  By the way, you might find some good ideas in this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475611/fastest-coincidence-matrix (ping @Divakar).